# How to duplicate the if-statement when the condition and statement have a similar pattern

Tags: excel, vba

I am making a VBA to transfer data to a new workbook. During the coding, I was wondering if I could simplify the `if statement` when the condition and the statement have a similar pattern.

It is something like:

```
Dim d As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim range_output As Range
Dim lRow As Long
Dim osh As Worksheet 'original worksheet
Dim sh1 As Worksheet 'output worksheet

Set osh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Original")
Set range_output = sh1.Range("C8:J38")

lRow = osh.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For d = 1 To lRow
        If osh.Cells(d, 3).Value = "APPLE" Then
            k = Day(osh.Cells(d, 1).Value)
            range_output.Cells(k, 1).Value = osh.Cells(d, 9).Value
        ElseIf osh.Cells(d, 3).Value = "ORANGE" Then
            k = Day(osh.Cells(d, 1).Value)
            range_output.Cells(k, 2).Value = osh.Cells(d, 9).Value
        ElseIf osh.Cells(d, 3).Value = "GRAPE" Then
            k = Day(osh.Cells(d, 1).Value)
            range_output.Cells(k, 3).Value = osh.Cells(d, 9).Value
        ElseIf osh.Cells(d, 3).Value = "LEMON" Then
            k = Day(osh.Cells(d, 1).Value)
            range_output.Cells(k, 4).Value = osh.Cells(d, 9).Value
            ...
        End If
Next d
```

I realized the condition is some type of fruit and the statement is similar. Then I tried to improve it by making a table and transferring it into an array.

```
Dim fruit_type As Variant
fruit_type = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data").Range("fruit").Value

If osh.Cells(d, 3).Value = fruit_type(1, 1) Then
   k = Day(osh.Cells(d, 1).Value)
   range_output.Cells(k, 1).Value = osh.Cells(d, 9).Value
ElseIf osh.Cells(d, 3).Value = fruit_type(2, 1) Then
   k = Day(osh.Cells(d, 1).Value)
   range_output.Cells(k, 2).Value = osh.Cells(d, 9).Value
ElseIf osh.Cells(d, 3).Value = fruit_type(3, 1) Then
   k = Day(osh.Cells(d, 1).Value)
   range_output.Cells(k, 3).Value = osh.Cells(d, 9).Value
   ...
End If
```

The pattern is more clean now. However, I still cannot simplify it by using a variant to duplicate a similar pattern. Simply using `for loop` within `if-statement` might lead to a wrong result. Appreciate it if you could advise any improvement.

Comment: You read data to `fruit_type` but then use `work_type` ?   If you use `Option Explicit` (and you really should) then you will get warnings about this type of problem...

Comment: @TimWilliams Oh! Sorry. I used `work_type` in my original code. To easily describe the question, I changed it to `fruit_type` but forgot to change it all.  Thanks for mentioning it. I have edited it.

Answer (score 1):

VBA has `Select Case` statements for this situation.

In the case of your example, the number of occurrences of `k = Day(osh.Cells(d, 1).Value)` can be greatly reduced.
The part `range_output.Cells(k, 1).Value = osh.Cells(d, 9).Value` needs a different approach.

Here is an example, I added `PINEAPPLE` for illustration.

```
Select Case osh.Cells(d, 3).Value
Case "APPLE", "ORANGE", "GRAPE", "LEMON"
    k = Day(osh.Cells(d, 1).Value)
Case "PINEAPPLE"
    'Do something else
Case Else
    'We need to exit if the value is not a known fruit, or the last statement in the sub will fail
    Exit Sub
End Select
Next d

Dim i As Long
i = WorksheetFunction.Match(osh.Cells(d, 3).Value, Array("APPLE", "ORANGE", "GRAPE", "LEMON"), 0)
range_output.Cells(k, i).Value = osh.Cells(d, 9).Value
```

Technically speaking, you could apply for the fruits the same kind of approach I did for the `i` variable, that is find if the value you are looking for appears anywhere in an array in a single function call.
I thought also presenting the `Select case` statement was more interesting as an answer to your question rather than implementing the same approach twice.

---

Side note#1:
 `Select Case`, unlike `If ... Then ...`, can be used to create short-circuit condition evaluation.

It is kind of an ugly hack but the below code is valid and it calls the 2nd function only if the first returned `False`:

```
Select Case True
Case FunctionCall1(x), FunctionCall2(y)

End Select
```

---

Side note#2:
It is slightly unclear to me how big `range_output` is but to speed up your code (in some case, to **greatly** speed up your code), I would recommend you modify the range only once, outside of the loop, in this fashion:

```
Dim outputValues As Variant
Redim outputValues(1 To range_output.Rows.Count, 1 To range_output.Columns.Count)

For d = 1 To lRow
    ' Do what you need here
    outputValues(k, i)= osh.Cells(d, 9).Value
Next d
range_output.Value = outputValues
```

Comment: It is genius to use `MATCH` to find the variant `i` within the array. Yet, I guess the line `i = worksheetfunction.match ... = osh.cells(d,9).value` should be put under the `Case "apple", "orange", "grape", "lemon"`. Since it needs the k value under the `d loop`. Really thanks for teaching me that much.

Comment: You can do it the way you describe but you do not have to. What sets `k` and `i` apart is that `k` is the same **value** for the 4 fruits whereas only the **formula** for `i` is the same (value is dynamic), and it could be applied to fruits listed in more than 1 case (e.g. `PINEAPPLE`) in which case it could be better to have it outside of the `Select Case` once rather than inside it several times.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your named range "fruit" has two columns - fruit name and column number for output:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim d As Long, col As Long, k As Long 'prefer Long over Integer
    Dim range_output As Range
    Dim osh As Worksheet 'original worksheet
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet 'output worksheet
    
    Set osh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Original")
    Set range_output = sh1.Range("C8:J38")
    
    For d = 1 To osh.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
        col = FruitColumn(osh.Cells(d, 3).value)
        If col > 0 Then 'got a match?
            k = Day(osh.Cells(d, 1).value)
            range_output.Cells(k, col).value = osh.Cells(d, 9).value
        End If
    Next d

End Sub

'Which column for fruit `v`?  Returns 0 if not matched
Function FruitColumn(v) As Long
    Dim res
    res = Application.VLookup(v, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data").Range("fruit"), 2, False)
    FruitColumn = IIf(IsError(res), 0, CLng(res))
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the use of a dictionary may be a good solution in your specific case.  As the discriminator is a string you can use a collection as the dictionary.

Edited to correct a rather silly mistake

```
Option Explicit

Dim d As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim range_output As Range
Dim lRow As Long
Dim osh As Worksheet 'original worksheet
Dim sh1 As Worksheet 'output worksheet
Dim myMap As Collection
Set myMap = New Collection
With myMap
    .Add 1, "apple"
    .Add 2, "orange"
    .Add 3, "grape"
    .Add 4, "lemon"
End With

Set osh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Original")
Set range_output = sh1.Range("C8:J38")

lRow = osh.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
' the line below appears to be the same for every if condition so does not need to be in the loop
k = Day(osh.Cells(d, 1).Value)
k = Day(osh.Cells(d, 1).Value)
k = Day(osh.Cells(d, 1).Value)
k = Day(osh.Cells(d, 1).Value)
For d = 1 To lRow
    ' cell references are row,col in excel
    ' assumed the value from osh.Cells(d, 3).Value is a number
    Dim myCol As Long
    myCol = myMap.Item(VBA.LCase$(VBA.Trim$(osh.Cells(d, 3).Value)))
    range_output.Cells(k, myCol).Value = osh.Cells(d, 9).Value
    'alternatively
    'range_output.Cells(k, myMap.Item(VBA.LCase$(VBA.Trim$(osh.Cells(d, 3).Value)))).Value = osh.Cells(d, 9).Value
Next d
```